# problem with const reference return and STL vectors

Tags: c++, stl, vector, reference, constants

I am having issues with the following snippet of code

```
    string const& symbol::at(int index) const {
    assert(index<symbol_data.vector::size());
    return symbol_data.vector::at(index);
    }
```

Here, symbol_data is a private member of the class and is a vector

::at is a member function in the symbol class that I have defined.

When I try compiling this code, I get the following error messsage:

```
    error: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’ used without template parameters
```

However, there is no error if I change the function prototype to

```
    string symbol::at(int index) {...}
```

Does anybody know how I can get STL vectors to work properly with const references?

Comment: Can you post a complete example that can be independently compiled?  (Preferably as small an example as possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as I'm writing this:

```
string const& symbol::at(int index) const {
    assert(index<symbol_data.vector::size());
    return symbol_data.vector::at(index);
    }
```

Instead of `symbol_data.vector::` write just `symbol_data.`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: That's what I thought, but all the compilers on my lappy accept `symbol_data.vector::at(index);`...

Comment: @James: huh. Can you post a complete example?

Comment: `int main() { std::vector<int>().vector::begin(); }`  Clang 3.0/133044, Visual C++ 2010 SP1, and g++ 4.5.1 all accept that (with `#include <vector>`, naturally).  I'm quite surprised!

Comment: This did the trick and got the code to compile.  Can you explain what is going on behind this?  Don't I need vector:: for scope resolution since I am re-using ::at and ::size in my custom class?

Comment: Oh. It compiles with Comeau Online also. It's not that surprising really, because inside the `vector` class template definition and I think its member function definitions you can refer unqualified to `vector`. And I think the name lookup is the same. But this makes the OP's problem more mysterious. I guess we'll have to wait for more complete code...

Comment: @user788171: Nope, `symbol_data` is a `vector`, so simply calling `symbol_data.at()` will call `vector::at()` instead of your `at()` function. I've never seen the syntax you're using being used anywhere else, but it does work, amazingly!

Comment: To add some more information, I am using g++ 4.3 on Linux (RHEL) with the -pedantic-errors option.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem; the following compiles and works fine on VS2010 express.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class symbol 
{
  std::vector<std::string> symbol_data;

public:
  symbol()
  {
    symbol_data.push_back( "Str1" );
    symbol_data.push_back( "Str2" );
  }

  std::string const& at( int index ) const 
  {
    assert( index < symbol_data.vector::size() );

    return symbol_data.vector::at( index );
  }
};

int main()
{
  symbol s;

  std::cout << s.at( 0 ) << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what my complete code looks like.  After removing vector:: it compiles fine, but it won't compile the way you have written it.